# Selection of vertices surrounding a vertex (only the the ones directly touching)

Tags: vertices

I need to use this without python coding.
Thanks, is there a shortcut or anything? I tried Crtl+L and just L and it just selects my whole model.

Comment: Pleas don't pout your question just in the title: use the editor text area to describe what you need, what you tried (add examples or screenshots) and what does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+ <kbd>numpad +</kbd> to select more vertices connected to the intitial selection.

[image]

Or use the